# I want to split the string and keep the first word only

Tags: pandas

I've a dataframe which contains details of cars. Now I want keep only the brand name and remove the model name.

I've tried using the str.split function to separate the car name. However it gives me a list and then I'm not able to extract the first name.

```
splitted = df['CarName'].str.split(' ',1)
```

Expected result:

```
alfa-romero
Audi
VW
```

Acutal result:

```
[alfa-romero, giulia]
[alfa-romero, stelvio]
[alfa-romero, Quadrifoglio]
[audi, 100 ls]
[audi, 100ls]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do in two ways, one as WeNYoBen explained in his comment, or by using extract against a list of Brands

```
df['brand'] =df['cars'].str.split(' ',1).str[0]
```

or

```
pattern =['audi', 'alfa-romero']
df['brand_2'] =df['cars'].str.extract("(" + "|".join(pattern) +")", expand=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Then you can do

```
splitted = df['CarName'].str.split(' ',1).str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with str.split

```
df['res']= df['CarName'].apply(lambda x : str(x).split(' ')[0])
```